# Normal distribution with few given data

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that we have a random variable X with normal distribution $N(μ,σ^2)$. What is $P(X>80)$, if we know that $P(X<60) = 0.1$ and $P(X>90) = 0.2$?

How would you go about this? Do we think about area under the curve? It seems that we don't have enough given to solve this problem.

Comment: Use $z=\frac{x-mu}{sigma}$. The $z$ can be found from the standard normal table. The $x$ is given, so two equations with two vars, doable

Comment: But we are not given a mu. Also, how is the x given?

Comment: you could also use the definition of $P(X<x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} p_{X}(x) dx $ where $p_{X}(x) = \frac{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2 }{2\sigma^2}  }  }{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2 }}$

Comment: For the values of $0.1$ and $0.2$ you can find a $z$ from the table. The x values are $60$ and $90$ respectively.

Comment: So in this case 0.1 and 0.2 are not z values themselves. They are areas, right?

Comment: No they are not

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Standardizing gives
$$P(X<60) = P\left(Z<\frac{60-\mu}{\sigma}\right)= \Phi\left(\frac{60-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = 0.1$$
where $Z$ is a standard normal distribution, and $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf. Using a calculator (or table), the inverse cdf $\Phi^{-1}$ gives
$$\frac{60-\mu}{\sigma} = \Phi^{-1}(0.1) \approx 0.54\implies 60-\mu = 0.54\sigma$$

You can use $P(X>90) = 0.2$ to find another equation. Then you will have two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: where is that 0.54 in the table?

Comment: use [this](https://imagebin.ca/v/31YxcMoVDrFI) table

Comment: @Brad Row "0.1", Column "+0.00".